# String split returns nil value error in lua

Tags: lua

I'm following a [lua doc page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin) on string splitting, get an error trying it myself. For example,

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
split("a,b,c", ",")
```

returns

```
stdin:1: attempt to call global 'split' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
stdin:1: in main chunk
[C]: ?
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[That](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin) isn't a "lua doc page". It is a wiki article explaining the *concept* of splitting and joining strings, not any actual functions in Lua. [The Lua documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/) clearly states that there is no "split" function. The wiki article is explaining how to *create* such a function and/or how such a function might work.

Answer (score 1):

The message is clear: you have tried to call a global function named `split`, but is not defined.